# How to make xampp automatically update the localhost

Tags: php, xampp, web, auto-update

I honestly don't have a clue what to put here... I have searched all over the web and can't seem to find anything useful :(

I am looking to make a website, but then I would like it to update each time I write something in the notepad (or at least when I save it) so I don't have to manually press F5 in my browser each time.

Does anyone know how to do so?

Comment: Include a javascript timer in your page to refresh the page at intervals

Comment: Similar question found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683417/localhost-wont-immediately-update

Comment: @rhea it has nohing to do with my question, believe me I searched everywhere

Comment: @MarkBaker This might be a solution but I would need guidance

Comment: [how to automatically reload a page after a given period of inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644027/how-to-automatically-reload-a-page-after-a-given-period-of-inactivity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a php script which check if your files are updated then you create an infinite loop or a timed loop on the client side to request this script. If it returns true (updated), you reload your page.

Theoricaly, it works but I discourage you to do it. It will consume a lot of cpu and will not be really usefull...

Comment: Tell me how! This is exactly what I am looking for, I only need it on whenever I edit the page ;)

Answer (score 2):

here is a free solution for you
you need to:

1. First install nodejs from [nodejs official website](https://nodejs.org/en/),
2. Then go to your windows command prompt and install [browser-sync](https://browsersync.io/) by writing the following code `npm install -g browser-sync`, where `npm` is node js package manager, `-g` is for global
3. Then you open the folder you want `browser-sync` to follow refresh updates in your terminal or command prompt and write the following code `browser-sync start --server --files <files which browser-sync wants to follow and refresh for you>` some files like `*.html *.css css/*.css *.js` dont put commas in between

one thing you need to remember is that you need to write the last command every time you want browser-sync

happy codding :)

Answer (score 1):

This is going to refresh your page every 10 seconds or whatever amount of milliseconds you input, but that is usually a bad solution, but it is easy and works! Hope this helps, dont forget to remove or disable it when you are done!

```js
setInterval(function(){location.reload(true);}, 10000);
```

Comment: Do I put this in the HTML file? It dosen't look like it belongs in there... o_O

Comment: it is javascript insert it with the script tags  <script> setInterval(function(){location.reload(true);}, 10000);
 </script>

Answer (score 1):

Prepros solved my problem.
[PrePros](https://prepros.io/)

- Open PHP project folder in Prepros
- Goto `Server options` and Select `External Server`
- Check `Use External Server` option and paste the Xampp Project Url. 
   
  [image: How to make xampp automatically update the localhost] 
  :)