# Why is my netbeans not updating my html code

Tags: php, html, caching, netbeans

Today I installed netbeans on my home computer to do some work at home. I installed the java 8 JDK (151) and installed netbeans with everything included (didn't do a custom install). I then pulled my project down from github.

My install folder for netbeans is on E:\netbeans
My project folder is the default on c:

I loaded the project, turned on XAMPP and ran it. Great, it works.

Then I made a change to the HTML (fixes a spelling mistake I made). Ran it again. It didn't take the change.

I made sure I had saved - still borked

I made sure Firefox was not caching my page - still borked

I tried it in a different browser, one that had never opened the project before - borked

I rebooted netbeans - borked

I deleted the cache in netbeans -borked

I rebooted my computer - borked.

Google searches for "Netbeans not applying changes" or similar things are not returning me with anything useful (all of the same it is the browsers cache, I have caching turned off in Firefox using about:config and I turned of memory and cache)

Windows 10 system
Netbeans 8.2 up to date (there are no updates available)
Project is HTML,PHP to a XAMPP database.

Anyone have some advice on this?

Edit: as suggested I ran it in Admin mode. It still behaved the same.

I am running it through Netbeans but I then just navigated to the page without clicking run in netbeans and it is the same.

Comment: Try netbeans open using administrator (run as administrator)???

Comment: how did you ran it. is it through netbeans?

Comment: @ThilinaMD I edited the post to reply but running it in admin didn't do anything. I am running it though the netbeans app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured this out and will post it here in case anyone else looks into it.

I installed netbeans and xampp on my E drive. The project I was editing was on the C drive in xampp/htdocs. When I would save it would save there. I am unsure how this happened but on the E drive was another copy of the project. When I ran the project it would run from the folder E:\xampp\htdocs instead of where the project was in c:\xampp\htdocs. Keep in mind, when you install xampp is will make the C: folder regardless of where you say to install it.

Anyway, if you are having this problem and you have two hard drives look and make sure there is not a duplicate project in the two htdocs. If there is, you might be saving to one and running the other.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem. Try ignoring cached content when reloading the page. These commands should work on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge:

For PC:

> Ctrl + Shift + R

For Mac:

> Command + Shift + R

Source:
[localhost Won't Immediately Update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55474249/17970328)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31476071)