# Changes made into example-sims (phet-sims) doesn't update the views into the browser, js npm grunt

Tags: javascript, html, npm

### Interactive Sims in HTML5 phet sims.

I follow the steps given in https://github.com/phetsims/phet-info/blob/master/doc/phet-development-overview.md successfully.
But every time i make some change at the code, i have to:

1. delete package-lock.json
2. run

```
npm install
```

3. run

```
npm cache clean --force
```

4. run again

```
http-server
```

5. And restart the browser on incognito or private mode

Question: How I can update the changes more eficient?

Others try: I tried diferents text editos vscode subblimetext notepad++
           and differents browsers firefox, chrome

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using in a Chrome browser this command to refresh recursively:

> ctrl + shift + r

Thanks this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55474249/6472513[forcing favicon refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55474249/6472513)